# Set Foreign Key to 'NULL' When delete Relationship in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent

My question is related to Laravel, I have `product` model and `categories`. They have a relationship with `category_id` as a foreign key to `product` table, my question is, I need when I delete a category, this `category_id` related field be `NULL`, I mean, there's a Laravel way to do it? Without be in `migration`.

This is my Category Model:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product');
}
```

This is my Product model:

```
    public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category')->withDefault(function ($data) {
        foreach($data->getFillable() as $dt){
            $data[$dt] = __('Deleted');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What happens when you delete a category right now ?

Comment: The category is deleted, but in my Product table, the category_id still there! and I should be NULL

Comment: so, there is no foreign key set in place ?  all the more reason to do a migration update.

Comment: The foreign key is in my product table, but should be null when I delete a category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**

I mean its probably possible but I wouldn't recommend doing something that way. You could theoretically do a database query that gets all products that have the category_id of the the category you just deleted, then update them to null as long as your column accounts for null values. You would simply call this (or some variation of this) whenever you're deleting a category. This may have major performance impacts based on the size of the table you're doing this on.

ie. (using model):

```
Products::where('category_id', '=', $id_i_deleted)->update(['category_id' => null]);
```

or (using DB):

```
DB::table('products')->where('category_id', '=', $id_i_deleted)->update(['category_id' => null]);
```

But I would highly recommend just biting the bullet and altering your table structure. It'll save you infinite headaches in the long run.

**Original:**

Yes, it is definitely possible! Here is how you should set up your foreign key if you want it to allow for a null value:

```
Schema::table('products', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('set null');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but theres another way to do it?

Comment: @calebesantana I've offered an alternative solution but I still recommend creating a migration to solve this problem. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Shorter way using a helper:

```php
Schema::table('products', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('category_id')->nullable()->constrained()->on('categories')->nullOnDelete();
});
```